# How to copy folder from server to client in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I'm trying to copy the folder from my server to the client the file is at the x directory.want to know how to set the file path in the server.

server side

```
filename = '/home/Desktop/features'
f = open(filename, 'rb')
while True:
    l = f.read(buff_size)
    while (l):
        self.sock.sendall(l)
        # print('Sent ',repr(l))
        l = f.read(buff_size)

    if not l:
        f.close()
        self.sock.close()
        break
```

client side

```
with open('red_fi', 'rb') as f:
    print('file opened client ')
    time.sleep(3)

    a = True

    while a:
        print('receiving data...')
        data = s.recv(buff_size)
        # print('data=%s', (data))

        if not data:
            f.close()
            # time.sleep(3)
            print('file closed client')
            a = False
            break
        # write data to a file
        f.write(data)

    # time.sleep(2)
    print('Successfully received the file')
    print(id_list)
    s.close()
```

I want the features folder to be copied from server to client.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Please describe in more detail what your actual problem is.